# Точка пересечения двух прямых

Tags: c

Пересечение двух прямых. Угол между ними и точка пересечения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно реализовать в коде(Си или же С++), на основе этих параметров прямых?

Answer (score 2):

1. Построить уравнение для *второй* прямой в виде `Ax + By + C = 0` (коэффициенты такого уравнения для первой прямой у вас уже даны)
2. Решить систему из двух этих уравнений относительно `x` и `y`. [Например, по правилу Крамера](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/lines_intersection). Если решение существует и единственно, то вы получите точку пересечения ваших прямых.
3. Коэффициенты `A` и `B` в этих уравнениях - это векторы нормали `(A, B)` к прямым. Угол между этими векторами - это и есть угол `α` между прямыми. Формула скалярного произведения векторов

   ```
   a ∘ b = 2 |a| |b| cos α
   ```

   позволит вам найти `cos α`, а затем и сам `α`